# High charts disable point halo animation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have modified the events for handling display of tool tips where I have synchronized two charts and one chart does not contain the same number of data points as the other.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jknipp/g3vr5v44/18/), specifically the top graph when the data points for 8/5 and 8/8 are hovered over. The points are no longer highlighted, but for a brief period the 'halo' animation is displayed.  I would like to prevent the halo on a per point basis from being visible to the user.

```
$('#success-graphs-container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
  var charts = Highcharts.charts.filter(function(chart) {
    return (chart.title.textStr.match(/success/i)) ? chart : null;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    chart = charts[i];
    e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
    points = [chart.series[0].searchPoint(e, true), chart.series[1].searchPoint(e, true)]; // Get the hovered point

    var show = function() {
      if (points[0] && points[1]) {
        chart.tooltip.refresh(points); // Show the tooltip
        points[0].onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
        points[1].onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker

        chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, points[0]); // Show the crosshair
      }
    }

    if (i == 0) {
      chart2 = charts[i + 1];
      e2 = chart2.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
      points2 = [chart2.series[0].searchPoint(e2, true), chart2.series[1].searchPoint(e2, true)];

      if (((points[0] && points[1]) && points[0].x != points2[0].x && points[1].x != points2[1].x)) {
        //points[0].onMouseOut();
        //points[1].onMouseOut();
            chart.tooltip.refresh(points); // Show the tooltip
        points[0].select(false);
        points[1].select(false);

          //Highcharts.each(chart.hoverPoints, function(point) {
        //    point.setState('');
        //});


        chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, points[0]); // Show the crosshair
        window.isOutOfSync = true;
      } else {
        window.isOutOfSync = false
        show();
      }

    } else {
      show();
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: to disable halo overall https://jsfiddle.net/f5L0ye4f/

Comment: I want to be able to enable/disable the halo on demand.

Comment: __on demand__ is what?. It is some event or based on data

Comment: Toggled based on data. If the point.x in graph A is different from point.x of graph B, then disable it, otherwise enable it.